# Using a Java ServerSocket for multiple Mobile Platforms?

Tags: java, serversocket

Is it possible for me to use A Java Programme that accepts Sockets using a ServerSocket to accept Sockets from multiple mobile platforms? e.g. Can I use my ServerSocket to connect to: An Android Phone, iPhone Phone, And Blackberry phones? I am trying to make one server for all phones because the server holds multiple data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. Why not? I would recommend using some sort of webservice.

I have been using [GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/) to run json webservices with [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for iphone and Android and it is going just fine.